# Generic PIC 40-Pin and 18-pin development boards

Tags: pic

I've looked at [Guide in choosing good overall PIC dev board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18322/guide-in-choosing-good-overall-pic-dev-board) page already, but didn't really find what I'm looking for. I have found some 18-pin, 28-pin, and 40-pin PIC development boards at Sparkfun http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/9 . However, I want to find out whether I can interchange different models PIC chips with the same number of pins onto the board. I'm looking for development boards that have similar level of peripheral support built-in onto the board like the Arduinos or T.I. Launchpads. What do you know of the options?

On a second note, where can I get economical PIC programmers?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell exactly what you are looking for, but we sell both PIC development boards and programmers.  Take a look at our [products](http://www.embedinc.com/products) page.

The ReadyBoard series is meant to make it easy for you to implement your own circuit around a PIC.  The board provides the basic infrastructure, like power supplies, RS-232 interface, reset control, debug LEDs, etc, but doesn't try to include "peripherals" as such since every project is different.  Instead we include a large breadboard area where you can add your own circuit that does just what you need.

The ReadyBoard-02 is targeted to USB applications and therefore comes with a 18F2550, but it is compatible with any 16F and 18F in the 28 pin DIP footprint.  Note that this is different from the PIC 24, 30, 32, and 33 28-pin footprint.

Comment: I guess your company doesn't sell any 40-pin footprint based PIC development boards?

Comment: @Stanigator: Not at this moment.  Several are in various stages of development.  They are proceeding slowly since we're swamped with consulting work right now, which is our main business.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Microchips' development boards and programmer. You can find enough choice at the [microchips'](http://www.microchip.com/) website, and the formalities are simple to buy through Microchip Direct.

Other better choice is [MikroElektronika](http://www.mikroe.com/) Development tools, which can be found at

http://www.mikroe.com/eng/categories/view/6/pic-development-tools/

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the product page for the 40-pin board, and the schematics seem a bit out of date plus the info is a bit lacking on supported chips.
It will certainly work for quite a few of the 40-pin PICs, and would probably be quite easily adjusted to work with others too.
You could work things out for yourself by looking at datasheets/pinout and check they match up with the board pins, but as this would take a while I would ask Sparkfun to give you a list - it says "see list of related ICs below" but then only gives 2, which is probably only the ones they stock, not the full list of compatible PICs.
I imagine most 16F and 18F 40-pin PICs will be compatible, but I don't think the dsPICs/PIC24 will be (I think they are slightly different IIRC I remember modifying a few 18F boards for dsPIC a while back)
I would also want to see a picture of the bottom of the board to check how the proto tracks are arranged and how easy it would be to modify. **EDIT** I noticed the 18-pin version does have a picture of the underside - it looks like stripboard with a few traces for the ICSP lines, so easily hackable.

You don't give any specific details about what kind of peripheral support you are interested in (the options are endless) but for a system with lots of different plugin options check out the [PIC18 Explorer](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en535770) (here is the [page](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2519&param=en025315&page=wwwPICmicroDemo) it came from with other options)

For an economical programmer that can be used with pretty much all the current PICs grab something like a PicKit 3. Or PicKit 2 if you want to go a bit cheaper and still program most PICs.

Answer (score 0):

I found some alternatives listed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_compatibles

Answer (score 0):

In August I decided to take a look at micro-controller development using PIC's. After searching for some time I found Matrix Multimedia's E-Blocks system.  It is worth taking a look.

[Matrix Web Site](http://www.matrixmultimedia.com/eblocks.php)